# File Size string Sorting In C# Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want to sort the `List<>` Data based on File Size which is stored in some string parameter, I tried the following way but it is sorting the list alphabetically and getting wrong result after applying sort.

```
private List<DirectoryItemInfo> SortByColumnWithOrder(string order, string orderDir, List<DirectoryItemInfo> data)
{            
    List<DirectoryItemInfo> lstDirItems = new List<DirectoryItemInfo>(); // Initialization.
    try
    {   
        lstDirItems = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ) ? data.OrderByDescending(p => p.FileSize).ToList()
                                                                                 : data.OrderBy(p => p.FileSize).ToList();      
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {             
        _logger.LogError("File Sort Attribute Exception, Error : {0} {1}", ex.Message, ex);
    }            
    return lstDirItems;
}
```

DirectoryItemInfo Class:

```
public class DirectoryItemInfo
{     
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string FileSize { get; set; }
    public string FileIcon { get; set; }
    public string FileModified { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Current result of Descending Sort:

```
File                            Size        Last Modifed
 VXALX5AXE.137999.Fax.txt      592 bytes   2016-02-19 12:07:21 AM 
 VXALX5AXE.137998.HTM          11 kb       2016-02-19 12:01:01 AM 
 VXALX5AXE.138000.Fax.txt      1 kb        2016-02-19 12:12:07 AM
```

Required result of Descending Sort should be like:

```
File                            Size        Last Modifed
 VXALX5AXE.137999.Fax.txt      11 kb       2016-02-19 12:07:21 AM 
 VXALX5AXE.138000.Fax.txt      1 kb        2016-02-19 12:12:07 AM 
 VXALX5AXE.137998.HTM          592 bytes   2016-02-19 12:01:01 AM
```

Any Idea about sorting this kind of Alphanumeric string would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends how you stored the filesize...... if you stored it as text as you have it complicates it

Comment: Store the filesize as an integer in kb, sort based on that and then create a method that converts filesize integers to a readable string, and call this on filesize when you are formatting the string.

Comment: here's a way using Linq and Regex: `List<string> sizes = new List<string>() { "592 bytes", "11 kb", "1 kb", "2 kb" };`
            `var ordered_sizes = sizes.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value));`

Comment: If you don't want an alphabetic sort, don't sort on a `string` value. See marked duplicate for example of sorting files. Your question's code is too incomplete to know what the best way to adapt that would be, but it's where you need to start. .NET APIs that give you file size return numeric values to start with, so if you have text values, either you're converting file sizes to text for no good reason, or this file data is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: If the file data is coming from somewhere else and you need to parse the units (e.g. "kb", "bytes", etc.) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035815/how-to-sort-a-listview-column-that-contains-file-size-data-c-sharp for details on how to deal with that.

Comment: @Innat3 thank you, Now my prob solved.